# creating multiple instances of a object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object

I am trying to create multiple versions of an object which has an init function. I have tried using the javascript 'new' function but in this case that does not work and the console notifies me this is because it is not a function. 
See the code for a clearer description of what I am trying to do.
I understand why this code will alert item two and not item one but I do not know how to get the correct behaviour.

```
var myApp = {
menu: {
        init: function (name) {
            this.name = name;
        },
        alertName: function () {
            alert(this.name);
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var first = myApp.menu;
    var second = myApp.menu;
    first.init('item one');
    second.init('item two');
    first.alertName();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clone your object. In javascript, your variables `first` and `second` are two references to the same object : when modifying `first`, you modify `second` too.

You can use `jQuery.extend()` to clone your object.

```
var first = jQuery.extend(true, {}, myApp.menu);
var second = jQuery.extend(true, {}, myApp.menu);
```

Comment: What is the main reason to use jquery here rather than the Object.create option in Tibos's answer

Comment: @Peter Saxton. For two reason : First, he has already used jQuery so it's not a problem to him to use a jQuery function. Second, `Object.create` function is not available before IE 9 ([MDN Object.create page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Cross-browser_compatibility)). When there is a choice, I choose the solution that provides the most compatibility.

Comment: Some considerations need to be mentioned: 1) this solution has a performance hit when dealing with many objects as it is cloning objects instead of using JS's prototypal inheritance. 2) on the MDN page below the compatibility table there is a polyfill for this exact use case which can be used if the OP wants to support ancient browsers.

Comment: JQuery often has great and useful methods, but with what costs? Imagine that for an extend of an Object to the deepness, JQuery would have to iterate recursively trough all the properties and copy them one by one. Is clear that it would raise performance issues over the native object instantiation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use javascript's constructor functions, and call `new` to instanciate different objects :

```
var myApp = {
    menu: function(name){
        // if menu is called as a constructor function, `this` will refer
        // to the object being built
        this.name = name;
    }
}

myApp.menu.prototype.alertName = function(){
    alert(this.name);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var first = new myApp.menu('item one');
    var second = new myApp.menu('item two');
    first.alertName();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eF5VK/1/)

Comment: I am looking to create copies of the object not using a constructor function. Primarily so I can use quite a large chuck of code I have already created.

Comment: Corum's and Tibos' answers are valid too.

Answer (score 3):

The reason only `'item two'` is alerted is because when you do `first = myApp.menu` and `second=myApp.menu`, both `first` and `second` refer to the same object. When you set the `name` property of that object (`this.name = name` in `init`), both references point to the same object with the changed property.

The simplest way to do this is like this:

```
var myApp = {
  menu : {
    init: function (name) {
       this.name = name;
    },
    alertName: function () {
      alert(this.name);
    }
  }
}

var first = Object.create(myApp.menu);
var second = Object.create(myApp.menu);
first.init('item one');
second.init('item two');
first.alertName();
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/OrEkaPe/1/edit

`Object.create` creates a new object (duh) and sets the parameter as prototype for the new object. When you access a property on the new object and it doesn't exist, it will be accessed from the prototype instead, giving you the inheritance you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 0):

Declaring objects with {} is actually inline initialization, is already an instance and not a constructor, one solution for your problem would be to create a declarative object.

Please refer to this reference for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

A quick implementation for your problem is here :

http://jsbin.com/OsoWECA/1/edit

```
var myApp = {
menu: function () {
        this.init = function (name) {
            this.name = name;
        };
        this.alertName = function () {
            alert(this.name);
        };
        return this;
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var first = new myApp.menu();
    var second = new myApp.menu();
    first.init('item one');
    second.init('item two');
    first.alertName();
    second.alertName();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `new` if you want, this should work:

```
var myApp = {
menu: {
        init: function (name) {
            this.name = name;
        },
        alertName: function () {
            alert(this.name);
        },
        new: function () {
            var func = function () {}
            func.prototype = this
            return new func;
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var first = myApp.menu.new();
    var second = myApp.menu.new();
    first.init('item one');
    second.init('item two');
    first.alertName();
});
```